# como usar o SELECT statement para ser inserido numa coluna na mesma tabela?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-select, sql-insert

```
SELECT Names,SUBSTRING(Names,10,50) AS Alias
  FROM NameToSplit;
```

*Aqui nao quero colocar as Alias, e sim INSERIR na coluna Alias esse SELEct statement.*

*depois preciso pegar essa coluna Alias e colocar esse outro script( nao tenho certeza se esta certo) e adicionar na coluna Aliases*

```
SELECT Alias,
       CASE LEN(Alias) WHEN CHARINDEX('.',Alias) + 4 THEN Alias
                            ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.',Alias)+5,0,'-') END

FROM (select Alias from NameToSplit)V(Aliases);
```

O resultado final precisa ser algo como:

```
Names-Alias-Aliases
idealink.core.user/core.user/core.user
idealink.core.userbadge/core.userbadge/core.user-badge
idealink.core.usergroup/core.usergroup/core.user-group
idealink.core.userloginhistory/core.userloginhistory/core.user-loginhistory
```

nao to conseguindo juntar tudo isso... :(

Comment: Se entendi corretamente você deve fazer um `UPDATE` e não um `SELECT`.

Comment: sou newbie, nao to conseguindo com a sintaxe,,...aonde eu teria q por o update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve fazer um `UPDATE` para isso:

```
UPDATE nametosplit
   SET alias = SUBSTRING(names, 10, 50);
```